# The Concept of Trivialism

Tags: logic

I understand trivialism is the position that everything is true, but I don't understand how it arrives there conceptually. The trivialist realizes that our natural (L)anguage (combined with our classical logic) is inconsistent because you can formulate the liar sentence that is contradictory either way. So by principle of explosion he gets

L, p & ~p |- q and L, p & ~p |= q (we assume our linguistic-logical system to be sound).

But by semantic *definition* p & ~p is false, so if q = p & ~p then it yields a false conclusion, so not everything becomes true! In classical logic it is just true that any q follows from a contradiction (p & ~p |- q), if the inference system is sound it is even true that if the contradiction was true then the conclusion were true (p & ~p |= q), but it is not true that q becomes always true because contradicitons are defined to be false and q can always stand for such a contradiction.

So it seems the trivialist must first and foremost manipulate the semantic definitions of truth (p, ~p, &, v, ->), but then he has no argument, he basically just *defines* his position.

Comment: You are not being bold enough, for a trivialist everything is also false, because "everything is false" is also true. Everything is both true and false. There is no need to manipulate anything, this is exactly the result one reaches in classical logic by adding a single true contradiction, like the Liar, which natural language supplies. Priest, a founder of dialetheism (where only *some* things are both true and false), called it "*certifiable insanity*", but Kabay recently wrote a long [defense of trivialism](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6714/93693da32d0b9c38aad857672021a950486a.pdf).

Comment: If **everything** is true, also  **p & ~p** is.

Comment: Is logic trivial? Or is the Liar paradox trivial? The latter gets my vote.

Comment: @Mauro: To my understanding the trivialist moves within classical logic. But then he can never arrive at his position. While it is true that you can infere anything from a contradiction, it is not true that the inferred is always true since 'p & ~p' is false by definition. So does the trivialist indeed start his position from 'everything is true'? Then it isn't classical logic anymore.

Comment: Being false by definition does not preclude something from also being true by definition, one simply assumes T=F and gets the trivial Boolean algebra. Classical logic does not prevent true contradictions from existing.

Comment: @Conifold: To my understanding classical logic does prevent true contradictions because it's by definition that 'p & ~p' is false. In a trivial (classical) system S you can infer S |- p & ~p and that proves that a trivial (classical) system doesn't produce only truths. The trivialist must FIRST assume that p = T and ~p = T and then indeed everything becomes true but it ain't classical logic anymore.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Defined to be false does not preclude something from also being true, and if all falsehoods are truths trivial logic produces "only truths". In particular, the trivial algebra with T=F is a model of Boolean algebra, i.e. satisfies all laws of classical logic.

Comment: If T = F then that's not classical (bilvalence) semantic. In classical semantic p & ~p is false and no trivial system changes that which means that even a trivial system does not produce only truths. Is that really wrong for it would mean I lack severe knowledge of logic.

Comment: It is just not the conventional terminology. Trivial Boolean algebra is still a Boolean algebra just as empty set is still a set, etc. It is convenient because we may not know in advance if a formal system built over classical logic is consistent, and hence non-trivial, so we would not even know if ZFC is a classical system under your convention.

Comment: Trivial Boolean algebra is not classical logic though. Classical logic is called "classical" because it defines: If p = T then ~p = F and if ~p = T then p = F. That's called principle of bivalence. And all I say is that a trivialist can't claim within such a system that even a trivial system produces only truths, i.e. a trivialist does not!!! use classical logic!

Comment: Those things hold in a trivial Boolean algebra, and T=F is routinely acknowldeged as a possibility for potentially inconsistent formal systems that are perfectly classical. So yes, to most people it is classical and trivialists do use classical logic, even if you disagree.

Comment: Can u give a link? I'd have sworn to my life that any system where T=F is not-classical. Again, to my knowledge, classical logic is basically classical semantics that T and F are never ever equal. I am confused now.

Comment: Classical logic is not semantics, it is defined in terms of laws, as you can see in [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/) or [Wikipedia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/). And trivialists "move" within the four corners of those laws. You can say that they pick non-classical semantics of classical logic, if that helps, but that happens after their argument from the laws.